# organizing symfony and doctrine configuration with oneToMany

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've never worked with symfony/doctrine before and am trying to do this right. I created a `ProjectBundle` and a `FeatureBundle`.

I have the following interfaces and classes in my `ProjectBundle`'s `Entity` directory:

```
Project.php (implements ProjectInterface)
ProjectInterface.php
ProjectItemInterface.php
```

In my app, a `Project` can have many `Features` but because I'm attempting to fully separate concerns, the `ProjectBundle` doesn't need to know about the `FeatureBundle`. I don't have any implementation of `ProjectItemInterface` because I envision it having many different implementations.

I plan on having a `CoreBundle` for my app that pulls all of the bundles together. I'm attempting to separate concerns like [Sylius](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/tree/master/src/Sylius/Bundle) is doing.

I'm baffled by how i should do the doctrine configuration in each bundle though. Here is what i have for `Project.orm.yml` in the `ProjectBundle`

```
Acme\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project:
    type: mappedSuperclass
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        createdAt:
            type: datetime
            gedmo:
                timestampable:
                    on: create
        updatedAt:
            type: datetime
            gedmo:
                timestampable:
                    on: update
            nullable: true
    oneToMany:
        items:
            targetEntity: Acme\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\ProjectItemInterface
            mappedBy: project
            orphan-removal: true
            cascade:
                - all
```

I'm confused though because the `ProjectItemInterface` is polymorphic. In my app's case it needs to be a `Feature` but i'll probably need to add some other entity type to it in the future, like `Task`s or something.

The `ProjectInterface` has generic `::addItem(ProjectItemInterface $item)` and `::getItems()` methods defined.

These methods make sense in the `ProjectBundle` but not in the `CoreBundle`. It seems like i would want methods like `::addFeature(FeatureInterface $task)` and `::addTask(TaskInterface $task)`. This is one area of confusion.

The other is what the `Project.orm.yml` file should look like in the `CoreBundle` because i will be extending that base `Project` entity and adding app specific properites and methods.

I've read up on [mapped superclasses](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) which i believe i'll be using when extending the base `Project` but i don't know how to configure the `oneToMany` `ProjectItemInterface` relationship in the `CoreBundle`. I've read a little bit about discriminator maps but i think thats for classes that extend each other. My `ProjectItemInterface` implementations won't extend a base `ProjectItem`.

To recap:

1. Does my bundle/entity structure make sense?
2. Is my `ProjectBundle` too generic and I should include the project stuff in my `CoreBundle` and be done with it?
3. If not, how do I configure a polymorphic `oneToMany` doctrine relationship for my `ProjectItemInterface` implementations in my `Project`?

```
    /CoreBundle
        /Entity
            Project.php (extends ProjectBundle's Project)
            ProjectInterface.php (extends ProjectBundle's ProjectInterface)
            Feature.php (extends FeatureBundle's Feature)
            FeatureInterface.php (extends FeatureBundle's FeatureInterface and ProjectBundle's ProjectItemInterface)
        /Resources
            /config
                /doctrine
                    Project.orm.yml (don't know what this should look like)
                    Feature.orm.yml

    /ProjectBundle
        /Entity
            Project.php
            ProjectInterface.php
            ProjectItemInterface.php
        /Resources
            /config
                /doctrine
                    Project.orm.yml

    /FeatureBundle
        /Entity
            Feature.php 
            FeatureInterface.php
        /Resources
            /config
                /doctrine
                    Feature.orm.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty big question.  I'm only going to address a couple of points.

Obviously you know quite a bit about separating stuff.  The fact that your are new to S2/D2 makes me want to suggest that you start by coupling your Project and Feature bundles until you become more familiar with how things work.  My concern is that you may spend too much effort just getting started.

Having said that, read through here:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html.

D2 allows you to relate your Project entity to the Feature entity via an interface which could be defined in your CoreBundle.  You can then specify the actual Feature class at runtime.  So your project never needs to know where the feature is coming from.  It has some limits but might suffice for your purposes.

A second approach is to avoid the D2 relationship stuff completely.  Instead, when a project entity is loaded have it dispatch an event which requests it's features.  A core event listener would pick up the event, cause the query and return the features.  This approach completely isolates the two bundles but of course can make it more difficult to do updates and such.

Hopefully, this at least gives you some hints on which direction to try.

Comment: thanks for replying! Yeah, i think i may just need to not focus on separation so much when getting started unfortunately. I hadn't seen that chapter in the symfony book. Interesting and may be what i need. I think there's an error in the chapter though. In the customer entity comments, "In this example, any methods defined in the InvoiceSubjectInterface are already implemented in the BaseCustomer". I think that statement is incorrect. The BaseCustomer shouldn't have invoice related methods in the `CustomerBundle`, right?

Comment: Nope.  In the example a Customer is an InvoiceSubject and thus needs to implement any InvoiceSubject methods.  Invoice is a different object completely.

Comment: right, but the InvoidSubjectInterface methods wouldn't be implemented in the BaseCustomer in the CustomerBundle, they'd be implemented in the customer class that extends the base customer in a CoreBundle if you wanted to isolate the CustomerBundle from the InvoiceBundle.

Comment: I guess the assumption is that the InvoiceBundle is independent but the CustomerBundle is dependent on the InvoiceBundle if the BaseCustomer class implements the InvoiceSubjectInterface.

Comment: You can put the InvoiceSubjectInterface in the CoreBundle.  So Customer and Invoice both depend on Core but not each other.  If the word Invoice bothers you then just call it SubjectInterface.  And like I said, it is limited.